# retrieve ALL rss feeds given a URL - php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

What I am trying to do is given a RSS Feed URL, retrieve the total number of articles **given a range of dates (01/01/2014 - presente date)**. For example, if you go to www.inoreader.com and paste this URL,http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml, you will be able to find the total number of articles for that feed.

I have tried a couple of things. One of them was using the following implementation shown in: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp)

The problem is that I can only get the first few articles using that implementation. Somehow, RSS Readers like inoreader, are able to get the history for a RSS Feeds. Could someone guide me so that I can get this feature implemented?

The following code, for instance, returns only the first few articles.

```
<?php

$xml=('http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml');

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

echo $x->length;

?>
```

Comment: You can't. Not with RSS. If Inoreader have histories on that RSS, its probably they already cached those feeds. You can with their APIs. For NYTimes check: http://developer.nytimes.com/

Comment: @cwps I was trying to use inoreader API to get all the articles they cached but couldn't figure it out. I used NY Times as an example but I want more URLs. Do you know how to use inoreader API or do you know of other API that would do this?

Comment: from https://www.inoreader.com/developers/stream-contents there is an `ot` method that means Start time (unix timestamp) from which to start to get items. I'm guessing that **this only works from the time you subscribed to that feed**. I don't think there are any services that will cached any feeds, if you haven't already subscribed to those feeds.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are "windows" of time, there is no way to go back in time beyond what's currently in the feed...
Now, if you subscribed to the feed using a tool like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com), you can already get a little more data (provided that the feed is already in Superfeedr as well).

As time comes, your coverage of the past content of the feed will get better and better. This is how feed readers can show you a lot of historical content.

Comment: I modified my question. What I meant to say was get the number of articles given a range of date. So if I enter 01/01/2014 to present date, it should return the number of articles. Is that possible?